# Laravel принятие файла через ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Здравствуйте, нужно сделать добавление картинки через ajax, но не могу принять файл (возвращает null), пожалуйста, подскажите что делаю не так.

ajax:

```
var form_data = new FormData('img', img_file.prop('files')[0]);
$.ajax({
          type: "POST", //Метод отправки
          url: "/upload_image", //путь до php фаила отправителя
          processData: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: form_data,
          success: function(success) {
            console.log(success)
            form_data = undefined;
            console.log('zbs' + form_data)
          }
        });
```

Контроллер:

```
public function upload_product_image(Request $request){
        $key = $request->key;
        $picture = Input::file("img");
        return response()->json(['picture' => $picture]);
}
```

Еще вопрос: как вместе с файлом одновременно передавать другие переменные?

Comment: HTML формы покажите для полного понимания

Comment: `form_data.append(name, value);`

Answer (score 1):

Лично у меня так

```
$('#image').change(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', $('#image')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/uploadAvatar',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        success: function (data) {

            d = new Date();
            $("#avatar").attr("src", data.file+"?"+d.getTime());
        }
    });
});
```

Вот контроллер

```
public function uploadAvatar(Request $request) {


    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $imageName = $user->id . '.' . $request->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();



    $mv = $request->avatar->move(public_path('avatars'), $imageName);

    $user->avatar =  url('avatars', $imageName);
    $user->save();

    $response = [
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => "Картинка профиля загружена",
        'file' => url('avatars', $imageName)
    ];
    return response()->json($response);
}
```